# Dismiss alert view in iOS by tapping outside or cancel button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, tap

I had a very strange problem, I want to dismiss the `UIAlertView` when the user either taps on cancel button or anywhere else. I had read almost all the post and couldn't find an answer that solved my problem do any of you have any idea how to do this? Please guide me through the steps, I will be very thankful for this.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:label.text
                                                message:label1.text
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"ཕྱིར་འཐེན།"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"ཉེ་ཆར།",@"དགའ་མོས།",@"ཉེ་ཆར་གཙང་བཟོ།",@"དགའ་མོས་གཙང་བཟོ།",nil];
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 0):

Call touchesEnded method. It'll help you dismiss alertView when user tap anywhere else on the screen

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.yourAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

and remember to create yourAlert as strong reference

Comment: I believe this way if you click Yes instead of cancel, you will 2 event of clicking Yes and Cancel both...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
// Add gesture
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOnView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                            action:@selector(dismissAlert)];
[alert addGestureRecognizer:tapOnView];
```

Then you can call a function that dismiss your alert